# REACT i'm malding because of "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import './BusinessList.css';

import Business from '../Business/Business';

class BusinessList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BusinessList">
        {
          this.props.businesses.map(business => {
            return <Business business={business} key={business.id} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BusinessList;
```

I've been playing around with this trying to solve the map of undefined although i have not made any progress towards actually solving it. Anyone here who has at least an idea i can work with towards a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the parent look like when it passes in the props to `<BusinessList>`? Are you sure that `this.props.businesses` has data if you were to log it to the console?

Comment: I don't see where the `businesses` prop is passed to the component.

Comment: Check that `this.props.businesses` is defined before you map it

Comment: Thank you lads but found the solution which was using condition ( see below reply for solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using condition.

```
     <div className="BusinessList">
        {
          this.props.businesses && this.props.businesses.map(business => {
            return <Business business={business} key={business.id} />
          })
        }
      </div>
```